# RabbitMQ Separate Rejected and Expired dead-lettered messages

Tags: header, rabbitmq, ttl

Is there a way to deliver messages that have been deadlettered because they were rejected to a different queue than messages that have expired?

I can imagine building a service that reads the 'all dead' queue, parses the header xdeath reason and separates the messages by reason, posting them on different queues.

But is there also a way in RabbitMQ to do a similar thing?

(The use case: I want to process the expired messages by a superfast service to quickly reduce the backlog (for instance after we have a database failure). But the rejected messages need to be handled by a service with a lot of debug logging enabled.)

Comment: Is it an option for you instead of rejecting (you mean dropping, yes?) just send message to other queue?

Comment: I meant dropping indeed. It might be the way to go: Have a deadletter queue for TTL expirees and in the cases of extreme service fails. When the service is behaving normally I could just sent it to a 'rejected' queue. This would be a valid approach to fix it in the software issue, I just wondered if RabbitMQ had any builtin solutions for this.